# Form Authentication : Roles (MVC 4) C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, roles

I am trying to implement Forms Authentication in my Application. I various examples and looked at the samples and questions provided in this forum and ASP.net MVC but I just can't get it to work.

I manage to authenticate my user but the roles does not seem to work :-(

I have setup my Web.Config as follow :

`<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>`

In my Controller I set the Index page to AllowAnonymous and then check in there if the user is authenticated. If not then redirect to the login page..

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString,string currentFilter, int? page)
    {
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

        }
//Find all the employees
        var employees = from s in db.Employees
                       select s;
//Pass employees to the view (All works fine)
return View(employees.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

This all is working 100%

My Login code looks like this :

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(User user, string returnUrl)
    {
        var myUser = db.Users.Where(b => b.UserName == user.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
        if(myUser != null)
        {
            if(myUser.Password==user.Password)
            {
                //These session values are just for demo purpose to show the user details on master page
                //Session["User"] = user;
                ICollection<UserAccessLevel> levels = db.UserAccessLevels.Where(b => b.UserId == myUser.UserId).ToList();
                //Session["levels"] = levels;

                //Let us now set the authentication cookie so that we can use that later.
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index","Employee");
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Message = "Invalid User name or Password.";
        return View(user);
    }
```

I also have the following code in the Global.asax file :

```
 protected void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    //let us take out the username now                
                    string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
                    string roles = string.Empty;

                    using (TrainingContext entities = new TrainingContext())
                    {
                        User user = entities.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);

                        roles = "admin";//user.Roles;
                    }
                    //Let us set the Pricipal with our user specific details
                    e.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
                       new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), roles.Split(';'));
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //somehting went wrong
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I log in my FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate executes and everything looks good. My User is set and my roles in the session is also there...

But when I click on the details of my Employee/Index screen it takes me back to the login screen (I expect it to take me to the details of the employee I clicked because I am logged in and I am setup as an admin role)

Please can you assist me to try and get to the problem. I sat for more than 18 hours already trying to figure this out.

I already looked at these solutions and as you can see most of my code comes from there...
codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-27splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF
codeproject.com/Articles/342061/Understanding-ASP-NET-Roles-and-Membership-A-Begin
codeproject.com/Articles/408306/Understanding-and-Implementing-ASP-NET-Custom-Form

in case you need more detail about my code you can also download it from GitHub
https://github.com/Ruandv/Training/tree/FormsAuthentication

I will appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Can you post waht you have in your Authorize attribute class?

Comment: I dont have a custom Authorize attribute class. I am making use of the standard one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to your Database and look for the table that assigns roles to users (probably generated by `SimpleMembership`?), does your user have an "admin" role?

Looks like you're only assigning the role in the `FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate` method without actually setting it in the DB.

```
// Your method (...)
User user = entities.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
roles = "admin";//user.Roles;
```

And, although I'm not entirely sure, `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` may be using your Role Provider and checking if the user has/doesn't have the role in the database.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the database part out. I added the role in the DB and everything worked. All that time wasted.